# VBA Function that Creates and Executes a Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am a total newb in the world of VBA and a bit over my head.  I have a background in Java, but I am wholly unfamiliar with VBA.

I'm working to improve on an already existing Excel workbook that is used to record time and attendance.  Each pay period is recorded on a worksheet.  I need to calculate the number of hours of "use or lose" leave that the employee has for the current year.  Employees are allowed to carry over a maximum of 240 hours of annual leave from one year to the next.  Anything above that is lost.  I have a formula that works fine, but for each sheet I have to update the formula and I'm trying to make it so I don't have to do that.  Hence, by dive into VBA.

I created a simple function that returns the correct formula as a string.

```
Function createFormula() As String
  
    createFormula = "=SUM(" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-240"
   
End Function
```

This returns the correct formula, that looks something like this =SUM('PP03:PP26'!I24)+I26-240

It seems like I am on the right track but I obviously need the function to execute.  I did some reading and I think what I need to do is to call Application.Evaluate to accomplish this.  I modified the formula as follows, but it still just returns the string.

```
Function createFormula()
  
  createFormula = "=SUM(" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-240"
  Application.Evaluate (createFormula)
  
   
End Function
```

I've tried a bunch of other things that I won't bother to list.  Posting this in the hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

***** Edit  *****
It was suggested that I elaborate on the problem I'm trying to solve.

Each timesheet has several other calculations that involve bringing leave balances forward from the previous sheet.  Past iterations of this timesheet, created by others and inherited by me, have formulas that are updated on each sheet. I was able to solve all of those except for the issue of calculating lose or use leave.

On each sheet we have:

Balance from Previous pay period, Annual Leave accrued, Annual leave
used and Total to carry over to the next pay period

Because on each sheet, I know how many pay periods are left in the year, it would be easy to calculate the use or lose balance if the amount accrued was a constant but it is not. At least not always.  I have formulas on each sheet that pre-populate the amount of leave accrued for that pay period.  So what I need to do is iterate through all of the sheets and add those values up.  Add that to the Total, subtract 240 and that is your use or lose.

I hope this helps to clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Once you dump your formula to the target range, it will automatically calculate. I can't see in your code where you are doing that.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  I'm afraid I don't know what you mean.  Can you clarify?

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem. Perhaps it would be better to look at the actual problem you are trying to solve with the timesheets, before diving into VBA formulas? At the worst you might find that the INDIRECT function can help.

Comment: Either do everything in VBA or everything on the worksheet. Having VBA code create a string that represents a WS Function can work if you also use VBA code to assign this string to a Cell: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = createFormula()` (But as I said I would rather have the logic completely in VBA or completly made with WS functions)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I have edited my question to provide more details as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would gladly use a VBA function that gets the value from cell I24 for all of the remaining sheets, adds them up and subtracts 240 but I don't have the first clue how to approach that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried writing a comment but it is way too long. Your function when you use it in the worksheet is a formula itself. And it is already being evaluated since it is returning the string formula. That is what you've written using below lines:

```
createFormula = "=SUM(" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & _
  ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-240"
```

If you want to return the value instead, then you should assign it to your function like this:

```
Function createFormula()

  createFormula = "=SUM(" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & _
    ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-240"
  createFormula = Application.Evaluate(createFormula)

End Function
```

This is just answering your question but as what others commented, this is not the best approach. HTH.

Comment: Thank you.  I recognize that this approach isn't ideal, but it saves me from having to do a ton of work re-writing the whole thing.

Comment: FYI you should not use `Application.Evaluate` unless *every* range in the formula being evaluated has a worksheet reference, or those unqualified ranges (eg `I26` above) will be sourced from whatever happens to be the activesheet: that may not be the one you expect, and will lead to your formula returning the wrong result.   `Worksheet.Evaluate` uses a specific worksheet context for the evaluation, so you should use that form here.

Comment: If you need to know which sheet the formula is being called from then `Application.ThisCell` is the cell containing the formula, and `Application.ThisCell.Parent` will be the containing worksheet.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I think I need to change my approach to this. Adding Application.Evaluate seems to work but I believe that I will run into the exact issue you mentioned. Another problem with my approach is that the function doesn’t execute when the sheet becomes active. I know I can add more code to trigger that but I’m concerned that I’m just borrowing trouble.