# Sum Values in a Cell Across a Range of Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook for time and attendance purposes, with separate worksheets for each two week pay period.

For each pay period, employees enter their hours worked and any leave taken.
Formulas bring leave balances from one pay period to the next.
Employees are allowed to carry over 240 hours of annual leave from one leave year to the next. Any annual leave at the start of the next leave year that is in excess of 240 hours is lost.

I must display on each sheet their projected "use or lose" annual leave balance.
The formula is

```
=SUM('PP03:PP02'I24)+I26-240
```

This accomplishes what I need. It sums the value of I24 (annual leave earned for a pay period) in a range of sheets starting with the next sheet to the right, adds their current annual leave balance and subtracts 240.

I have to go to every sheet in the workbook and modify the formula to change the range.
My goal with this workbook is to have a single sheet that I create and then duplicate 25 times without having to update anything.

Employees annual leave accrual is based on time in service so it can change in the middle of the year.
I have other formulas that calculate that and populate Cell I24 on each sheet.

I tried to write a UDF that returned a formula as a string.
With [VBA Function that Creates and Executes a Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77691358/vba-function-that-creates-and-executes-a-formula), I wrote this function.

```vb
Function calcUseOrLose()

  calcUseOrLose = "=SUM(" & "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-I24-240"
  calcUseOrLose = Application.Evaluate(calcUseOrLose)

End Function
```

This works but the function doesn't execute when the sheet becomes active and there were other problems with my approach in general that were pointed out.

So more generally, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, looks like an interesting task, would like to help you. Need some clarification - you want to update formula when you add a new sheet in a such way, that formula grabs all previous sheets in it? e.g. If you have only `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` formula should look like  `=SUM('Sheet1:Sheet2'I24)+I26-240` on the `Sheet2`, and in case you add `Sheet3` it sould be updated to `=SUM('Sheet1:Sheet3'I24)+I26-240` and placed on that `Sheet3`?

Comment: @vitaliy-prushak You are close. I need to update the formula so that it calculates for the next sheet to the right through to the last sheet.  Pseudo code would look like: 
``` =SUM('currentSheet +1:lastSheet'I24)+I26-240 ```

Comment: Simplify this question to be much shorter and specific and simple to the problem (vs. the circumstances/story surrounding)

Comment: @pgSystemTester In another post, I was asked to provide more details so I was trying to provide more information this time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to put a formula in the cell on the `Workbook_NewSheet` event.

Here's how to do:

Go to VBE (Alt+F11), doubleclick "ThisWorkbook" link:

[image]

Select the "Workbook" in "(General)" dropdown list

[image]

By default, the Workbook_Open event handler will be generated, but you need to select the "NewWorksheet" event in dropdown

[image]

Event handler code will be generated and run each time you add a new sheet

[image]

Here you may put the code:

```
Sh.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & "'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(Sh.Name).Index - 1).Name & ":" & Sh.Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-I24-240"
```

and it will be generated on each new sheet.

Brief explanation:

1. When new sheet is created, this event receives this new sheet as argument: `ByVal Sh As Object`
2. The code identifies new sheet's index: `Sheets(Sh.Name).Index`
3. And takes prevoius to use in formula: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(Sh.Name).Index - 1).Name`
4. Along with newly created: `... & ":" & Sh.Name & "'" & ...`
5. And other your data: `... & "!I24)" & "+I26-I24-240"`

All you need to do - is just fix the targeting cell for the formula to be inserted (in my sample the formula will be inserted into the A1 cell - `Sh.Cells(1, 1)`)

**NB**

This will work good unless you don't change the sheets' order manually, otherwise, you will have to fix formula manually

***Added as per condition for copying sheets***

In this case you may either dig for workarounds on how to catch the worksheet_copy event (long and hard way) or use a sub to update formulas when you have copied all needed sheets:

```
Sub update_formulas()

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Index > 1 Then
        sht.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & "'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(sht.Name).Index - 1).Name & ":" & sht.Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-I24-240"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

You can run it from VBE or assign to an ActiveX button on a separate sheet, in the last case you can create a separate sheet, called, say, "Button" and use this code from a button there:

Code for a button:

```
Private Sub update_formulas_Button_Click()
update_formulas
End Sub
```

And code for the sub:

```
Sub update_formulas()

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Index > 1 And Not sht.Name = "Button" Then
        sht.Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & "'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(sht.Name).Index - 1).Name & ":" & sht.Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-I24-240"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

These are quick fixes, but I'm interested in this question, so will have a look for a UDF modification as well.

**Final**

I ended up with following.

1. I've reevaluated your formula:
   [image]
2. Translation to undertandable task:
   [image]
3. Simplifying it:
   [image]
4. Finally, coming up to this:

The code

```
Function calcUseOrLose()
    
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 1 Then

calcUseOrLose = "=" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Cells(24, 9).Address(External:=True) & "+" & ActiveSheet.Cells(26, 9).Address & " - 240"
Else
calcUseOrLose = 0
End If
    
End Function
```

Please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much! this works perfectly when I create a new sheet using the + button. However, I create new sheets by copying the existing one by selecting "Move or Copy" after a right click on the sheet I want to duplicate.  Is there a different event I can use?

Comment: @ScottA I have modified an answer

Comment: Your updated code was a real help.  I used a button on a hidden sheet called "lists" used for look up values.  I modified your sub as follows  <br/>
```Sub update_formulas()

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Index > 1 And Not sht.Name = "lists" And Not sht.Name = "Instructions" And Not sht.Name = "Start" And Not sht.Name = "PP02" Then
        sht.Cells(27, 10).Formula = "=SUM(" & "'" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets(sht.Name).Index + 1).Name & ":" & Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name & "'" & "!I24)" & "+I26-I24-240"
    End If
Next
End Sub ```

Comment: @ScottA I've also done with a UDF, please see it

Comment: I'm still new to commenting on this site.  My apologies for the formatting mess in my previous comment.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding about what it needs to do.  The formula needs to sum the value of I24 in the next sheet and all remaining sheets, not the previous sheet, so ActiveSheet.Index +1.  I added a second If statement to your sub above to handle the unique case of PP02 and that solution is doing exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep things as simple as possible and have formulae that can be copied from one sheet to the next without having to change them.

Taking your first Formula =SUM('PP03:PP02'I24)+I26-240.
I presume that you have manually named the sheets - which takes time.
I would drive the formula from cells on the sheet rather than the sheet names.
Imagine Cell B2 contains "PP03" and Cell C2 contains a formula that generates the previous pay period.
Your formula then becomes =SUM(B4+INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!B4")).
What this does is add the value in B4 to the value of the B4 on the previous sheet. The Indirect function converts the concatenated text back to a working formula.

There are 2 more formulae to make it all work nicely.

The first is to calculate the sheet name of the current/next sheet.
Starting with PP01 this gets converted to PP02 by
=IF(SHEET()="<10","PP0"&RIGHT(C2,1)+1,"PP"&RIGHT(C2,2)+1)
The IF statement is there to manage both the 01 to 09 periods and then onto the periods with double digits.

The second formula brings up the previous sheet's "sheet name".
=IF(SHEET()<"10",INDIRECT("'PP0"&SHEET()-1&"'!$B$2"),INDIRECT("'PP"&SHEET()-1&"'!$B$2")).

This only leaves you with manually naming the sheets PP01 ...PP26 per year.
That can be automated but requires a VBA macro to do that. I can show you how if valuable!

Comment: This answer looks like it would work but I had some trouble wrapping my head around it and I was already following the solution provided by @Vitaliy . Thanks for your willingness to help!

Comment: My solution avoids using VBA - either macros or UDFs.
It's like all things with Excel - always several ways to solve a problem.